# SQL: A query that verify referential integrity across all tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have created my tables and populated it but I am not sure how to write a query to verify the referential integrity across all tables.

This is what I need:

- SELECT lists all primary keys
- FROM lists all tables
- WHERE shows all relationships

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    categId, zipCode, suppId, acctId, prodId, orderId
From
    CATEGORY, ZIP, SUPPLIER, ACCOUNT, SUPPLIER_REGION, PRODUCT, PROD_DETAIL, ORDERX, ORDER_LINE_ITEM
```

I am not sure what to put for WHERE.

My professor wants a command to verify the referential integrity. There are a lot of other stuff he wants but this is the only thing I am not sure how to do.

I added my tables.

```
create table CATEGORY (
    categId varchar (8),
    categIdParent varchar (8),
    constraint CATEGORY_PK primary key (categId),
    constraint CATEGORY_FK foreign key (categIdParent) references CATEGORY (categId)
);

create table ZIP(
    zipCode int (5),
    city varChar (16),
    state varChar (16),
    constraint ZIP_PK primary key (zipCode)
);

create table SUPPLIER (
    supplId int (9),
    supplName varChar (24),
    supplStatus varChar (16),
    supplYearEstabl date,
    zipCode int (5),
    constraint SUPPLIER_PK primary key (supplId),
    constraint SUPPLIER_FK Foreign Key (zipCode) references ZIP (zipCode)
);

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER_REGION (
    supplId int (9),
    region varChar (24),
    constraint SUPPLIER_REGION_PK primary key (supplId, region),
    constraint SUPPLIER_REGION_FK foreign key (supplId) references SUPPLIER (supplId)
);

create table PRODUCT (
    prodId int (11),
    prodDescr varChar (256),
    prodType varChar (12),
    prodModel Char (16),
    prodPlaceOrigin Char (16),
    prodPrice decimal (10,2),
    prodMinQty int (8),
    supplId int (9),
    categId varchar (8),
    constraint PRODUCT_PK primary key (prodId),
    constraint PRODUCT_FK1 foreign key (supplId) references SUPPLIER (supplId),
    constraint PRODUCT_FK2 foreign key (categId) references CATEGORY (categId)
);

create table PROD_DETAIL (
    prodId int (11),
    prodDetailNo int (8),
    prodDetailName varChar (32),
    prodDetailValue decimal (10,2),
    constraint PROD_DETAIL_PK primary key (prodID, prodDetailNo),
    constraint PROD_DETAIL_FK foreign key (prodID) references PRODUCT (prodID)
);

create table ACCOUNT (
    acctId varchar(50),
    acctName varChar (24),
    acctDept varChar (16),
    acctTitle varChar (16),
    acctGender Char (1),
    acctEmail varChar (24),
    acctAddr varChar (24),
    zipCode int (5),
    acctPhone int (11),
    constraint ACCOUNT_PK primary key (acctId),
    constraint ACCOUNT_FK foreign key (zipCode) references ZIP (zipCode)
);

create table ORDERX (
    orderId int (8),
    orderPayMethod varChar (16),
    orderShipDate date,
    acctId varchar (50),
    constraint ORDER_PK primary key (orderId),
    constraint ORDER_FK foreign key (acctId) references ACCOUNT (acctId)
);

create table ORDER_LINE_ITEM (
    orderId int (8),
    orderLineNo int (8),
    orderLineQty int (8),
    orderLineUnit int (8),
    orderLinePrice decimal (10,2),
    prodId int (11),
    constraint ORDER_LINE_ITEM_PK primary key (orderId, orderLineNo),
    constraint ORDER_LINE_ITEM_FK1 foreign key (orderId) references ORDERX (orderId),
    constraint ORDER_LINE_ITEM_FK2 foreign key (prodId) references PRODUCT (prodId)
);
```

Comment: Why would you need to "verify" referential integrity? Did you forget to define foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server one good way is to create a diagram in SSMS. As you place each table into the diagram the FK relationships will be rendered as lines between tables and primary keys will be displayed as "key" icons.